Add text to point(s) in Kusto linechart
I have a kql script that creates the table at bottom and the line chart here:

Using kusto, is it possible to display text on one or more points, as
where it says "Champion" below in this line chart?

kql code
myquery
| render linechart with ( 
    legend = hidden, title = myracer,
    ymin=0, ymax=4,
    xcolumn=Place, xaxis=linear, xtitle="Location",
    ycolumns=Stage_Num,  ytitle="Stage"
)
;

Table


It is not currently possible to add text to point(s) in a Kusto linechart like originally requested. However, with help from @RithwikBojja, we were able to display text on a linechart with user toggle, and it comes with colored data points.

You can use below KQL query to get the text to points:
let rith = datatable(Value:int, valu2:int, String:string)
[
    2, 2, "Winner"
];
let rith_table = datatable(Value:int, valu2:int)
[
    1, 1,
    2, 2,
    3, 1,
];
rith_table
| project Value, valu2, String = "Hello Rithwik"
| union (rith)
| project Value, valu2, String
| render linechart with ( 
    legend = hidden,
    ymin=0, ymax=3,
    xcolumn=Value, xaxis=linear, ycolumns=valu2,  ytitle="Emo axis",xtitle="Vammo axis"
)

Output:

Fiddle.
UPDATE:
let rith = datatable(Place:string, Date:string, Stage_Num:int, String:string)
[
    "Room1", "1/30/23", 3, "Winner"
];
let mytable = datatable(Place:string, Date:string, Stage_Num:int)
[
  "Room1", "1/30/23", 3,
  "Room2", "2/1/23",  1,
  "Room3", "2/3/23",  2
]
;
mytable
| project Place, Date, Stage_Num, String = "Hello Rithwik"
| union (rith)
| project Place, Date, Stage_Num, String
| order by Date asc
| render linechart with ( 
    legend = hidden,
    ymin=0, ymax=5,
    xcolumn=Place, xaxis=linear, ycolumns=Stage_Num, ytitle="Stage", xtitle="Place"
)

Result


If I understand it correct, the display string is visible only when toggling over the data point, so doesn't meet my needs...how did you get the data point to be red?!

Yes, hovering needs to be done as we can give text to points, but you cannot display text every time as it is a kql output, but not power bi or any other.

I updated my question with my attempt to implement your code, but my data points disappear. Suggestions? (the update has to be approved). I forgot to include the toggle in the image, but it just shows 'Stage_Num: 3'

Add series=String like this https://i.imgur.com/j7TDJIt.png | render linechart with (          legend = hidden,         ymin=0, ymax=5,         xcolumn=Place, xaxis=linear, ycolumns=Stage_Num, ytitle="Stage", xtitle="Place",series=String     ), Now it will work
